# Nonparametric bootstrap with the fitdistrplus package

Tags: r, bootstrap

Suppose I use the nonparametric bootstrap to fit a model as so:

```
  BucketFit <- fitdist(x,"weibull",  method = "mle", lower = c(0,0))
  BucketBoot = bootdist(BucketFit, bootmethod = "nonparam")
```

However, if I look at BucketBoot, there's a `$fitpart` component as well as `CI` component that gives me the distribution and CI. However, since I'm using nonparametric bootstrapping, these aren't actually used?

However, if I got to `BucketBoot$estim` I get bootstrapped values of parameters. So it still does a fit?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`?bootdist` tells you:

> **Value**
>
> *fitpart* The object of class "fitdist" on which the bootstrap procedure was applied.

Thus the `fitpart` is just your previous fit: `BucketBoot$fitpart == BucketFit`
non-parametric bootstrap here means that bootstrap samples are generated by resampling from the original data with replacement (in contrast to generation of bootstrap samples from the fitted model that happens with the default `bootmethod = "param"`).

So to directly answer your questions: No, the fitted parameters are not used for the bootstrap in this case (Or only as a good starting point to speed up the bootstrap fits). And yes, it will do one fit for each bootstrap sample.

On a side note: the bootstrap CIs given by `fitdistrplus` are percentile CIs, you might want to compute [basic bootstrap CIs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(statistics)#Deriving_confidence_intervals_from_the_bootstrap_distribution) instead.